# How do you modify the label of checkboxes in a dynamically generated table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I am new to javascript/Jquery and have the following issue:

I am trying to modify the label of the checkboxes in a dynamically generated table :

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$18,000.00</b> ($18000+) Diamond Sponsor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$10,000.00</b> ($10000+) Ruby Sponsor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$5000.00</b> ($5000+) Emerald Sponsor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$3600.00</b> ($3600+) Gold Sponsor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$1800.00</b> ($1800+) Silver Sponsor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$1000.00</b> ($1000+) Bronze Sponsor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$500.00</b> ($500+) Pillar<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$250.00</b> ($250+) Patron<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$180.00</b> ($180+) Supporter<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$100.00</b> ($100+) Friend<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$50.00</b> ($50+) Donor<br>
<input type="checkbox"> <b>$25.00</b> ($25+) Donor<br>
</td>
```

I need to hide part of the label text for each of the inputs when it displays. Specifically the numbers surrounded by the parenthesis.

Currently this is how it looks:

**$18,000.00** ($18000+) Diamond Sponsor
 **$10,000.00** ($10000+) Ruby Sponsor
 **$5000.00** ($5000+) Emerald Sponsor
 **$3600.00** ($3600+) Gold Sponsor
 **$1800.00** ($1800+) Silver Sponsor
 **$1000.00** ($1000+) Bronze Sponsor
 **$500.00** ($500+) Pillar
 **$250.00** ($250+) Patron
 **$180.00** ($180+) Supporter
 **$100.00** ($100+) Friend
 **$50.00** ($50+) Donor
 **$25.00** ($25+) Donor

How can I remove the numbers including the parenthesis from input label but leave the rest of the label intact.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't just wrap that text in a span with a class and hide it?

Comment: A. Wolff is right the markup is not good.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match your question text: do you need the remove the parenthetical numbers for *all* of the checkboxes (which is what the body of your question implies), or only for *checked* checkboxes (like your title says)? (If the former, can't you simply not write out the parentheticals?)

Comment: Can’t you simply change the generating software so that the parenthetic expressions are not there? Surely this can be handled in client-side JavaScript after the table has been generated (but a robust solution requires more specific information about the context and conditions), but why?

Comment: @Martha Sorry about that, title updated. The question is for the former as you stated. I'm new to this and learning as I go, so I don't quite understand what you mean by "... write out the parentheticals...". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @jukkaK.Korpela Unfortunately no, the generating software is a SAS that allows for design updates through custom coding.

Comment: @Andre, I basically had the same question as Jukka: If you don't want them there, surely it's easier to not put them there in the first place than to jump through hoops afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

**jQuery:**

```
$('td').html(function (_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\(.*\))/ig, '<span class="hide">$1</span>');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u7veg/)**

Comment: The example supplied in your JsFiddle example is the result I'm looking for but after applying the script, the <span> tag is applied around everything between "$18,000.00" and "Donor" instead of each instance of the number with parenthesis.

The output is now one line that looks like: $18,000.00 Donor

Thanks for taking the time to help, I appreciate it.

Comment: No, in the fiddle it's applied properly. If it's not being applied properly on your page then something else is interfering. Ex: `<input type="checkbox"> <b>$500.00</b> <span class="hide">($500+)</span> Pillar
            <br>`

Comment: I'm working in a CMS that is a SAS so there may be something in the way the code is generated prior to running the script thats causing the issue. Hopefully I can figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"> <span><b>$18,000.00</b> ($18000+)</span> Diamond Sponsor<br>

$('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){

   $(this).closest('span').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Where does the OP mention he wants to be able to toggle the text? You've also taken the liberty of wrapping the text in spans that the OP didn't post in his question.

Comment: Additionally you have used .closest() it will search for the parent spans right.?

Comment: @Tyagi Sorry about the miscommunication between the title and the actual description. Thanks for the suggestion.